# Oracle: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON with Toad

Tags: oracle

I put **SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED FORMAT WRAPPED**; in **glogin.sql**, but **Toad** doesn't seem to take this configuration. In other words, the following PL\SQL wpuldn't print output:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');
END;
```

How could I make Toad auto shows PL\SQL output?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

glogin.sql is a script run automatically by SQL Plus; as far as I'm aware Toad does not run this script.  In Toad there is a "DBMS Output" pane at the bottom of the Editor window, and a red button at the top left of the pane to turn output on.