# Oracle single row into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to get all result in one row... it is working but when i want to see it in dbms there is nothink.. why ?

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NXMESEP.SP_IN_CHECK_AND_SEND_SMS

(    RC_TABLE0   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    RS_CODE            OUT        VARCHAR2,     -- RETURN 코드
    RS_MSG             OUT        VARCHAR2
    ) IS   ERROR_EXCEPTION            EXCEPTION;

BEGIN 

     begin
        DECLARE
        promena varchar2(32767);

            BEGIN

                OPEN RC_TABLE0 FOR
                SELECT listagg(ITEM_ID,', ') within group(order by ITEM_ID)
                 INTO promena
                  FROM TB_PL_M_WRKORD WRKOD
                WHERE 1 = 1
                AND WO_DATE = '20181012'
                AND WRKOD.ITEM_ID NOT IN (SELECT ITEM_ID FROM TB_CM_M_FERT_COST_CHK FERT)
                AND WC_ID = 'U';
                LOOP
                FETCH rc_table0 INTO promena;
                EXIT WHEN rc_table0%NOTFOUND;
                dbms_output.put_line(promena);
                END LOOP;
                  CLOSE rc_table0;

               end;
                   EXCEPTION
    ....    END;

   RS_CODE := 'S';    RS_MSG := 'Complete successfully!';

   RETURN; END SP_CHECK_AND_SEND_SMS; /
```

This should be promena that i expected..

```
" 12993NXUA, 13595NXUA, 14495NXUA, 16589NX, 16589NX, 16590NX, 16590NX, 16622NX, 16622NX "
```

Now it is working but im getting unknown error ORA-65535 every time when i execute. But after this I can see dbms result is ok.

Comment: Im using toad for oracle.

Comment: and i cant even use that variable, because it is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON with Toad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1699443/1509264)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT listagg(ITEM_ID,', ') within group(order by ITEM_ID) FROM TB_PL_M_WRKORD WRKOD
                   WHERE 1 = 1
                   AND WO_DATE = '20181012'
                   AND WRKOD.ITEM_ID NOT IN (SELECT ITEM_ID FROM TB_CM_M_FERT_COST_CHK FERT)
                   AND WC_ID = 'U' 

Is working, but then in "promena" is nothing and i cant see values that I can see if I run this code in new window as just select.

Comment: No i can see "Test" but promena doestn appear

Comment: I know where it is but this variable is still null there is only "test" || null

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to show the output you do see, and more context about your code - from elsewhere this seems to be part of a procedure with an out parameter. so showing at least the whole procedure (or at least the relevant parts, including the declaration) and how it's called and used would be useful. (And [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52888040/edit), don't add code as comments or as answers, please.)

Comment: It is done and working just another problem.

Comment: Now is working sending SMS too but i dont know what to do with that ERROR

Comment: Solved just bad settings of executor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your real code has `RC_TABLE0` declared, as a ref cursor, then your variable ends up null because opening the cursor *into* something doesn't really do anything. You can't open a cursor and select something from the cursor query into a separate variable at the same time, whichever way round you try to do it. You need *either* a cursor, *or* a simple `select ... into`:

```
DECLARE
  promena varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(ITEM_ID,', ') within group (order by ITEM_ID)
  INTO promena
  FROM TB_PL_M_WRKORD WRKOD
  WHERE 1 = 1
  AND WO_DATE = '20181012'
  AND WRKOD.ITEM_ID NOT IN (SELECT ITEM_ID FROM TB_CM_M_FERT_COST_CHK FERT)
  AND WC_ID = 'U';

  dbms_output.put_line('test: '||promena);
END;
/

test: 12993NXUA, 13595NXUA, 14495NXUA ...

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You also have to `set serveroutput on` or equivalent to actually see the results, of course.

I've also removed the redundant `distinct`, the unnecessary `select .. from dual` - which seemed to be part of the odd cursor construct - and the extra level of `begin/end`.

Incidentally, your code implies that `wo_date` is a string, which seems unlikely, or at least not ideal. If it is actually a real date then you should not be using a string for the comparison as you're forcing implicit conversions; use an actual date instead, maybe as an ANSI date literal:

```
  AND WO_DATE = DATE '2018-10-12'
```

---

If you did really want to use an explicit cursor approach you would need to use a loop to populate the string variable:

```
DECLARE
  promena varchar2(32767);
  rc_table0 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN rc_table0 FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT listagg(ITEM_ID,', ') within group (order by ITEM_ID)
    FROM TB_PL_M_WRKORD WRKOD
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND WO_DATE = '20181012'
    AND WRKOD.ITEM_ID NOT IN (SELECT ITEM_ID FROM TB_CM_M_FERT_COST_CHK FERT)
    AND WC_ID = 'U';

  LOOP
    FETCH rc_table0 INTO promena;
    EXIT WHEN rc_table0%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('test: '||promena);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE rc_table0;
END;
/
```

As you're only expecting a single row back there isn't much point doing that; and if you expected multiple rows (from a modified query, e.g. getting several days data and grouping by day) then an implicit cursor would be simpler anyway:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT listagg(ITEM_ID,', ') within group (order by ITEM_ID) AS promena
    FROM TB_PL_M_WRKORD WRKOD
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND WO_DATE = '20181012'
    AND WRKOD.ITEM_ID NOT IN (SELECT ITEM_ID FROM TB_CM_M_FERT_COST_CHK FERT)
    AND WC_ID = 'U'
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('test: '||r.promena);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

If this is really part of a procedure and the `rc_table0` is an `OUT` parameter then you just can't do this. In code you posted as an answer you tried:

```
OPEN RC_TABLE0 FOR
  SELECT listagg(ITEM_ID,', ') within group(order by ITEM_ID)
  INTO promena
  FROM TB_PL_M_WRKORD WRKOD
  ...
```

In that construct the `into` is still ignored, because the `open` doesn't fetch anything. And if you loop and fetch inside your procedure to display the results as I did above then you are consuming the result set, so the caller will get no results (or "ORA-01001: invalid cursor" if you close it inside the procedure).

You just can't do both, unless you re-open the cursor, which seems like overhead you probably don't want...

Comment: Thanks now I see the promena but still is there problem unknown error ORA-65535, I need it just for taking one row to send it after into SP that will send SMS.